# Multiplying normal distributions by a constant

Tags: normal-distribution

When working with normal distributions, please could someone help me understand why the two following manipulations have different results? Is $X + X$ different from $2X$?

Take $X$ to be normally distributed with mean and variance $X\sim N(2, 3).$

$Z = X + X$ is also normal, i.e. $Z\sim N(4, 6)$.

$Q = 2X$ is also normal, i.e. $Q\sim N(4,12)$.

For reference, I'm using the proof/technique described here - https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/26/26.1

Comment: Is $X$ independent with $X? $ The formula that you seemed to use does depend on independence.

Comment: Sorry, yes, let's assume that X + X is the sum of IID random variables

Comment: Take iid $X_1, ~X_2,~X.$ You can indeed talk about their sum's distribution using the formula but being iid doesn't mean $X_1= X_2.~X=X;$ so, $X+X$ and $X_1+X_2$ aren't the same thing.

Comment: Right! Thank you. That actually makes it a lot clearer why the two are not the same. 
1 and 2 may be IID , but that does not mean that 2 * 1 is equal to 1 + 2

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/51974cc364d2f1e05f0fcffd39277655) is a Python gist showing histograms and descriptive statistics of samples of $X, Z, Q$. You will find $Q=Z$. This is distinct from summing IID random variables.